# unknown filesystem type 'fat32' when trying to mount /boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gentoo

i was trying to do a modification to my gentoo kernel, and while i was doing the installation i got this error when trying to mount /boot, "`unknown filesystem type 'fat32'`." i looked around on the internet and thought the solution would be to just reboot. when i rebooted, the system booted, but the keyboard wouldn't work, and in the boot process it gave this "`Some local filesystem failed to mount`" error. now, i'm trying to recover my old kernel from a live ubuntu usb, following [this guide on the gentoo website.](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:Recovering_from_a_kernel_boot_failure) however, when attempting to `mount -a`, it throws me the exact same error i had initially, "`unknown filesystem type 'fat32'`." what exactly do i do here? thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you try to mount the device you want to mount to `/boot` from the livecd’s own prompt? The livecd probably needs to try to plug some modules to add FAT support on the fly while modules won’t be accessible from within the chroot. Once you have mounted the device successfully from outside the chroot, then go ahead with the chroot commands.

Comment: And when you do get the ability to install a fixed kernel, make sure to include appropriate FAT32 support (at least as modules) so that you can mount `/boot` from within your booted Gentoo environment in the future ;-).

Answer (score 2):

i had to change my `fstab` file to accept `vfat` instead of `fat32` to fix this issue. everything's good to go!